# async Task<IEnumerable<T>> throws "is not an iterator interface type" error

Tags: c#, asynchronous

The following code is throwing ***is not an iterator interface type*** only when I use `async` `await` and wrap the `IEnumerable` with Task. If I remove `async` `await`, it will work with `IEnumerable<List<T>>`.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<List<T>>> GetTableDataAsync<T>(CloudTable cloudTable, TableQuery<T> tableQuery)
        where T : ITableEntity, new()
    {
        TableContinuationToken contineousToken = null;
        do
        {
            var currentSegment = await GetAzureTableDateAsync(cloudTable, tableQuery, contineousToken);
            contineousToken = currentSegment.ContinuationToken;
            yield return currentSegment.Results;

        } while (contineousToken != null);

    }
```

Though I can consider Rx, I am not sure what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Only methods declaring that they return `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerator<T>` can be implemented with iterator blocks. That rules out all async methods.

Fundamentally it's not clear how they'd work anyway, given that `IEnumerable<T>` is pull-based, whereas asynchronous methods are more reactive. Also, the point of an iterator block is that callers can see intermediate results - whereas the task returned from an async method will not complete until the async method itself has completed.

You'll need to go for an alternative approach - whether that's Rx or something else. You might want to think first not about what the *implementation* will look like, but what the *caller* will do. Perhaps you actually want an `IEnumerable<Task<List<T>>`?

Comment: Maybe "IEnumerable<Task<List<T>>" will do. Requirement is to read all the azure tables' values and come up with some metrics (count of, sum of), the number of tables are more than 4k and the records for the given filter condition will go on in millions. I don't want to waste thread by waiting idle for the data to come back from azure

Comment: @Saravanan: So you need to think about what your client code will look like. It's entirely possible that iterator blocks won't really help you here - because they're a blocking pull model.

Comment: Went ahead with Rx. Recently published a NuGet package that provides a reactive interface to table storage using `WindowsAzure.Storage` sdk - [Reactive.AzureStorage.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Reactive.AzureStorage.Table/)

Answer (score 28):

old question, and the accepted answer is correct, however now with c#8, IAsyncEnumerable was introduced. so instead of IEnumerable you should use the IasyncEnumerable. see the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#asynchronous-streams

Example:

```
public static async System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<int> GenerateSequence()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
await foreach (var number in GenerateSequence())
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Comment: Extremely good to know about IAsyncEnumerable! This is extremely nice!!! I wish I knew about this earlier!!